# Is there a way that we can stack trace where to where the things are being made to happen

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have  a rails 3.2 that is upgraded to rails 5.0 and why is the problem of overwriting existing metho i dont know

i have a new project in which the scopes are getting overrided at some point where is the that place in the project i cannot figure that out 
if i go maincontroller#index action then i could not see some sentence that does the overriding and where can i find the trace of that where the scope is getting overrided

**W, [2019-11-08T14:41:41.608933 #20597]  WARN -- : Creating scope :track_allowed. Overwriting existing method CustomFieldDefinition.track_allowed.

W, [2019-11-08T14:41:41.609093 #20597]  WARN -- : Creating scope :document_allowed. Overwriting existing method CustomFieldDefinition.document_allowed.

W, [2019-11-08T14:41:41.609198 #20597]  WARN -- : Creating scope :image_allowed. Overwriting existing method CustomFieldDefinition.image_allowed.

W, [2019-11-08T14:41:41.609284 #20597]  WARN -- : Creating scope :video_allowed. Overwriting existing method CustomFieldDefinition.video_allowed.

W, [2019-11-08T14:41:41.784878 #20597]  INFO -- : Processing by MainController#home as HTML

D, [2019-11-08T14:41:41.787093 #20597] DEBUG -- :   Track Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tracks".* FROM "tracks" WHERE (tracks.purged_at IS NULL)
I, [2019-11-08T14:41:41.790494 #20597]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms | Path: http://localhost:3000/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pry gem. Add `binding.pry` into the code and run `show-stack` when it pauses